# Which power supply topology is this?

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply

I cannot relate the power supply topology to any standard topology. It is very similar to Sepic but the Mosfet placement is different.It utilizes one coupled inductor instead of two inductors. Which DC to DC converter toplogy is this?

Comment: Do you have any context? Where did you find this circuit? What was it used to power?

Comment: Where did the circuit come from?

Answer (score 3):

This is indeed a variation on SEPIC.  Remember in SEPIC, although "technically" there are two separate inductors, *in practice* often they're combined onto the same form (and are thus coupled directly) to reduce costs and bulk.  Since both inductors carry similar voltages, with proper phasing they can share the same core.

The difference here is that the "switch" T1 sinks its conduction current to the *output* rather than *ground*.  This implies to me that the output is quite a bit lower in voltage than the input -- really a combination SEPIC with a buck twist.  If you separate N1 and N2 (write them as separate inductors, ignoring the common core) the topology is identical with [Figure 1 in the wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-ended_primary-inductor_converter) except that T1 connects to the output instead of ground.  Incidentally this adds a 2nd source of output to the circuit -- not only the diode output, but also the source of T1.  So the designer introduced "current sharing" resistors R1 and R2 which connect both "incoming" sources to their common output.

I bet R1 and R2 are identical (or nearly so).  That would further confirm that the voltages across the inductors are similar and that their common core is not functioning like a transformer so much as it is a common host to two inductors whose interfering magnetic influences are, in fact, not a problem in this particular case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had the same interpretation but was not very sure. R1 and R2 is same as shown in the figure. Does the equations of standard sepic topology apply to this? I think I have to derive the equations.